# Can I disable the X clear button on IE10 textboxes?

Tags: internet-explorer-10

In an application we use at work we have various textboxes, with dropdown buttons right next to them.

Our users are frequently accidentally pressing the X added by IE10 and clearing what they typed.

IE10 adds a clear button to all textboxes:
[image: Normal text box]

In our application it is right next to the dropdown button, meaning it's often clicked by accident:
[image: Problem in 3rd party application]

Is there a way of hiding/disabling/removing the X? Ideally something we can push out via a policy.

Note that we have no control over the application they are having trouble with.

Comment: Maybe your users need to be more careful. I'm sure they manage to click maximize rather than the red X to close IE10, it's no different.

Comment: I would like to tell them this, but I don't think they'd think of that as very helpful. I can see their point of view though, clearing is a very rare operation, they nearly always need to click the dropdown. It's silly to have the less common action button right next to the very common one so if I can avoid it, I'd like to. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a user style sheet:

> Options > General tab > Accessability button > "Format documents using my style sheet"

Add the following style to your new style sheet:

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

---

Edit: To manage this group policy etc try adding registry key "User Stylesheet" with value "X:\mystylesheet.css" (or whereever) under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Styles`

---

Further edit: You'll also need another key in the same location, "Use My Stylesheet" = 1

---

One last thought:  I know you said you don't have control of the application but don't forget you can always put a transparent proxy between your users and any web application.  [Here's a amusing example showing how you would do this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html), using squid as your proxy.

Comment: This looks great, can this be managed globally?

Comment: Doesn't this approach affect **all** websites though?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett I have updated my answer to include the required keys for managing globally.  I found the keys via google, I've not tested this.  Dave Rook: Yes, all websites, but you should be able to inspect the HTML of the app in question and build a more specific CSS rule that will only impact that application.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Trixie](http://www.pcworld.com/product/952510/trixie.html) in IE as it can be website dependent. Add this CSS:

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear 
{
    display: none;
}
```

The problem is though, this will have to do be done browser by browser.

Edit

As per comments by @Arjan

Trixie and [the like](http://sourceforge.net/projects/trixiewpf45) are installed in the browser; they won't be part of your application.

Comment: I don't have control over the application.

Comment: @George (a bit late...) and future readers: Trixie and [the like](http://sourceforge.net/projects/trixiewpf45) are installed in the browser; they won't be part of your application.